# How to "make friends" TestContainers Webdriver Containers and ParameterizedTest (JUnit5)

Tags: testcontainers-junit5

I have a problem with running @ParameterizedTest via TestContainers.
@Test running via TestContainers, but as soon as I change to @ParameterizedTest, then everything starts running on my local Сhrome instance.
In TestContainers's documentation I didn't find some information about @ParameterizedTest.

This is working:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.visible;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
import static conf.Configuration.BASE_URL;

public class Test {

    private final SelenideElement errorAuth = $(By.xpath(ErrorNotifications.ERROR_AUTH));
    @Rule
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome =
            new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
                    .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = chrome.getWebDriver();
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void search() {
        open(BASE_URL);
        new StartPage()
                .clickEnterButton()
                .enterLogin("var1")
                .enterPassword("password")
                .clickEnterButton();
        errorAuth.shouldBe(visible);
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This isn't working:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.visible;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
import static conf.Configuration.BASE_URL;

public class Test {

    private final SelenideElement errorAuth = $(By.xpath(ErrorNotifications.ERROR_AUTH));
    @Rule
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome =
            new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
                    .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = chrome.getWebDriver();
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"var1, var1", "var2, var2", "null, null"})
    public void search(String email, String password) {
        open(BASE_URL);
        new StartPage()
                .clickEnterButton()
                .enterLogin(email)
                .enterPassword(password)
                .clickEnterButton();
        errorAuth.shouldBe(visible);
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations:

```java
// These are JUnit 4 classes
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;

// These are JUnit 5 classes
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
```

So when you run your tests with the `@ParameterizedTest` annotation in place you're using the JUnit 5 runtime which will ignore the JUnit 4 annotations (`@Before`, `@After` and `@Rule`).

One way to make your parameterized test work is to replace the JUnit 4 annotations with appropriate JUnit 5 counterparts.

For that to work you'll first need the [Testcontainers JUnit 5](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) integration. E.g. as a Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you:

- Annotate your test class with `@Testcontainers`
- Use the `@Container` annotation instead of `@Rule`
- Replace `@Before` and `@After` with `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach`

so your class would look something like this:

```java
@Testcontainers
public class Test {

    ...

    @Container
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
                    .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        ...
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        ...
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"var1, var1", "var2, var2", "null, null"})
    public void search(String email, String password) {
      ...
    }
}
```